# using R's rPython to run python's rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2, rpython

I'm trying to use R to run a function I've written in python. *That* function uses some methods from R. So when I import the function from rPython, it crashes, probably due to circular import.

Essentially, my R code may be reduced to:

```
library(rPython)
python.exec("import rpy2.robjects")
```

Which results in immediate termination of R.

Note: the code above is just for demonstration, in my code I'm doing something useful, e.g:

```
library(rPython)
python.exec("from my_package import foo")
```

And the `import rpy2.robjects` is within `my_package.py`.

How may I organize my code such that I won't get this circular importing?

Comment: in my experience, `rPython` was rather limited and unreliable if used beyond simple stuff. Surely the new `reticulate` package offers a more advanced interface to Python

Comment: reticulate indeed seems much better, however I'm encountering the same crashes

Comment: Backup and give us a full picture. What does Python do (i.e., sources the data)?  What does R do (i.e., runs a method)? Then abstract both only once instead of duplicating their environments.

Comment: R runs a python method which imports an R method. The crash occurs only when running the method from R. At the moment my solution was to push the rpy2 import down to the specific part within the python method where it's required, and enabling sending R result as an input to the python method. This way I'm sort of hacking my own function. It's messy, but working.

Answer (score 1):

The crash is likely caused by the embedded R being initialized twice.

There is a discussion about introducing environment variables to capture the initialization status of R [here](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/98) and initial implementations should be in reticulate and rpy2 (although it was still crashing last time I tried).